# What does it mean to get saved?

Tags: word-meaning

In every 5th song someone sings about saving someone (for me it feels like this).

For example in the songs:

*Ty Dolla $ign - Saved*

*Oasis - Wonderwall*

Does it have religious or sexual mean?

Comment: Not necessarily, "saved" can be from a physical danger or an emotional one, or a tricky situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no sexual, and only a vague religious meaning to "saved" in Wonderwall. The song seems to be written to a friend or lover who will help the singer to sort out their life.  Sometimes a person needs help to sort their life out, even if they know what they should do, they still need help to actually do it.

The other song just seems to be a stream of obscenities, I have no idea if "saved" has any deep meaning; I suspect not.

The notion of being saved is central to Christian belief, and as such it has a profound impact on English speakers, even those who are not Christian.  However, there is no direct religious reference in either song.

Comment: A Jehovah's Witness once asked me if I was 'saved' in the street, and, do you know, after 10 minutes, it was _him_ who made an excuse and walked off! I gave him St Paul, Aquinas, the indwelling of the Holy Spirit, and a lot more besides.